# Kotlin Compose Multiplatform Desktop Open Camera & Take a shot

Tags: kotlin, camera, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, android-camerax

I want to open computer's camera and take a shot with kotlin compose desktop. CameraX is just for android. Not works on desktop. And there is no tutorial for this subject. Maybe opencv solve this but it so complex. I just take a shot. I want a simple solution.

Comment: There is 2 ways to do this. One is native solution another is use a javascript to open webcam. But java's own browser doesn't support webcam.

Comment: For native solution https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture is best 3rd library but it has problems with macOS. and kotlin Multiplatform.

Comment: Adding to codaman comment, the view for that library would require javax swing. You can integrate swing into compose by following this guide https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Swing_Integration/README.md (the SwingPanel part)